# select data from table with many clauses where

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I try to select data from database table with many conditional clauses where my code looks like that

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT "+  
                AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_FILE_NAME+" FROM " + 
                AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_FILE + " where "+ 
                AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_FILE_CATEGORY+" = "+ category+","+
                AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_THEME+" = "+theme+","+ 
                AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_CREATING+"="+date);
```

I know that this is code is not correct, How can I correct it

Comment: `how can i correct means ?` any error or exeption ? i think you should do correct yourself.No need to put simple and debugging  question here.

Comment: Try yourself before posting here, there is nothing in your question for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use one WHERE and combine conditions with AND

... where a=5 AND b=7 AND c='Ivan'